# Postgres group by date(timestamp) and sum value.

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below table entries.

```
mydb=> SELECT username, input_bytes, output_bytes, updated_at from radius_acct;

 username | input_bytes | output_bytes |       updated_at
----------+-------------+--------------+------------------------
 sandeep  |      255081 |        42154 | 2014-05-08 09:34:13+00
 sandeep  |      250281 |        42254 | 2014-05-09 09:34:14+00
 prashant |      258081 |        42354 | 2014-05-10 09:34:15+00
 arun     |         493 |         1215 | 2014-05-17 11:16:53+00
 arun     |        9421 |         3657 | 2014-05-17 11:21:38+00
 arun     |       18325 |         4504 | 2014-05-17 17:12:53+00
 prashant |      254081 |        42454 | 2014-05-11 09:34:16+00
 raj      |      255081 |        42554 | 2014-05-12 09:34:17+00
 raj      |      250681 |        42554 | 2014-05-13 09:34:18+00
 raj      |      253081 |        42654 | 2014-05-14 09:34:19+00
 kumar    |      295081 |        47254 | 2014-05-15 09:34:16+00
(11 rows)
```

I want to sum the input and output bytes and display it in MB and group the username by date.

My query do not group the date and sum it up and displays a similar output as shown below:

```
mydb=> SELECT username, input_bytes, output_bytes, ROUND((SUM(input_bytes + output_bytes)/1048576)::decimal, 2) AS total, date(updated_at)  from radius_acct group by username, input_bytes, output_bytes, updated_at ORDER BY username ASC ;
 username | input_bytes | output_bytes | total |    date
----------+-------------+--------------+-------+------------
 arun     |         493 |         1215 |  0.00 | 2014-05-17
 arun     |        9421 |         3657 |  0.01 | 2014-05-17
 arun     |       18325 |         4504 |  0.02 | 2014-05-17
 kumar    |      295081 |        47254 |  0.33 | 2014-05-15
 prashant |      254081 |        42454 |  0.28 | 2014-05-11
 prashant |      258081 |        42354 |  0.29 | 2014-05-10
 raj      |      250681 |        42554 |  0.28 | 2014-05-13
 raj      |      253081 |        42654 |  0.28 | 2014-05-14
 raj      |      255081 |        42554 |  0.28 | 2014-05-12
 sandeep  |      250281 |        42254 |  0.28 | 2014-05-09
 sandeep  |      255081 |        42154 |  0.28 | 2014-05-08
```

**Expected output:**

```
username | input_bytes | output_bytes | total |    date
----------+-------------+--------------+-------+------------
 **arun     |       28239 |         9376 |  0.03 | 2014-05-17**
 kumar    |      295081 |        47254 |  0.33 | 2014-05-15
 prashant |      254081 |        42454 |  0.28 | 2014-05-11
 prashant |      258081 |        42354 |  0.29 | 2014-05-10
 raj      |      250681 |        42554 |  0.28 | 2014-05-13
 raj      |      253081 |        42654 |  0.28 | 2014-05-14
 raj      |      255081 |        42554 |  0.28 | 2014-05-12
 sandeep  |      250281 |        42254 |  0.28 | 2014-05-09
 sandeep  |      255081 |        42154 |  0.28 | 2014-05-08
```

Row one arun is total of three rows.

Comment: I see you haven't accept any of the answer till date even though it helped. Please accept few answer which were of good help to you and pay respect to someone's effort. Along the way earn some rep also yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Try this once

```
SELECT username, 
sum(input_bytes) as totalinputbytes, 
sum(output_bytes) as totaloutputbytes, 
ROUND((SUM(input_bytes + output_bytes)/1048576)::decimal, 2) AS total, 
date(updated_at) as update_date
from radius_acct 
group by username, date(updated_at)
ORDER BY username;
```

Comment: @user1564173, then it's time for you to accept the answer by clicking the check button under voting button.